# Flask + WTForms - Single Table One to Many Form

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Given a pricing table/model of product_number, customer_id, price, how do I create a form that displays all customer/price values for editing given that one product may have 10+ customer, price combinations?

I successfully populate the pricing object with:

```
def editprice(product_number):
    pricing = Pricing.query.filter_by(product_number=product_number).first_or_404()
    form = PricingForm(obj=pricing, next=request.args.get('next'))
```

And can successfully display and edit the values of the first customer price combination with a simple form:

```
class PricingForm(Form):
    next = HiddenField()
    product_number = HiddenField(u'Product Number', [Required()])
    cust_id = IntegerField(u'Customer', [Required()])
    price = DecimalField(u'Price', [Required()])
    submit = SubmitField(u'Save')
```

But I'm not sure what needs to happen to get a form that displays all customer, price inputs for a given product_number.  Do I need to iterate over the form objects in the template or is there a change required to the form?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.